# reading from an array and writing into a servomotor

Tags: arduino-uno

I have an Arduino Uno.
I am trying to write a code that reads a command and according to that command it saves angles into an array or writes the angles of the array into a servomotor.
I am facing some problems with my code such as executing the instructions of boucle FOR without ending and other strange things.

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo s;
int t[6];
int n, r = 2, b = 4 ;
char c;
String ch = "" ;
int i = 0;
int nb, rep = 0;
int cmd = -1;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(r, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(b, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(r, LOW);
    digitalWrite(b, LOW);
    s.attach(9);
    t[0] = 0;
    t[1] = 90;
    t[2] = 180 ;
}

void loop() {
    while ((cmd == 0) || (cmd == -1)) {
        cmd = lirecmd();
        delay(20);
    }

    if (cmd == 1) {
        digitalWrite(r, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(b, LOW);

        while (i < 3) {
            while (Serial.available() > 0) {
                c = Serial.read();
                ch.concat(c);
            }

            if (ch != "") {
                nb = ch.toInt();
                t[i] = nb;
                i = i + 1;
                ch = "";
            }
        }
    } else if (cmd == 2) {
        int x;
        cmd = -1;
        digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(r, LOW);

        for (i = 0; i < 3; i = i + 1) {
            Serial.print(i);
            x = t[i];
            delay(1000);
            s.write(x);
            delay(1000);
            break;
        }
    } else {
        digitalWrite(r, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
    }

    i = 0 ;
    cmd = -1;
    rep = 0;
    digitalWrite(r, LOW);
    digitalWrite(b, LOW);
    delay(50);
}

int lirecmd() {
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        n = Serial.read() ;
        n = n - 48 ;
    }

    return n ;
}
```

Comment: Please find a style guide. It will make your code easier to read.

Comment: You should rearrange your code.

Global variables, like that
    int i = 0;
are not a good idea: it makes the code much harder to read and much easier to make mistakes, by using the wrong variables in the wrong places.

Also, try to break down all those nested loops, create functions with a meaningful description.
That too will help making the variables more local: pass parameters and return values.
As empirical rule of thumb, do not nest more than 1 or 2 times and keep the functions 10-15 lines long.

If you cannot do it, there is probably something wrong in your algorithm.

Comment: ok,i will try to do that,thx.